# CSS !important does not override styles from external stylesheets

Tags: css

In a stylesheet, I have this:

```
body {
  color: white !important;
}
```

Notice how it doesn't work on the text on the right side of this page:

https://www.graf.ly/graph_templates/56/

You can inspect the text, and see that the style was applied, but then overridden. How is this possible?

I thought !important ignores CSS specificity, and acts as a directive to always use that style. I've never seen this behavior before.

**Note:**

Don't be fooled by the white text by the graph's axis, that is a `text` svg element and was colored with `fill: white !important`.

Also, I'm well aware of the correct usage of !important. So please no comments or answers saying "you should never use !important". That is not the question :)

Comment: mifi79 answered the question very well, but for a practical rule to correct this behavior, I suggest `#legend, #legend .label { color: inherit; }`.  Not really an answer because the answer is that it doesn't inherit the body color attribute.  This just solves your localized problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This has nothing to do with CSS specificity or `!important`. You have a rule in main.css that says:

```
#legend .label {
  color: black;
}
```

The selector is targeting the `.label` elements directly and giving them a color, which prevents them from inheriting the color from the body or some other ancestor. An `!important` property applies only to the element that is targeted; it does not force other elements to inherit that property. In other words, a specified rule always takes precedence over an inherited rule, even if that inherited rule is `!important`.

See the spec:

> User agents must first assign a specified value to each property based on the following mechanisms (in order of precedence):
>
> 1. If the cascade results in a value, use it.
> 2. Otherwise, if the property is inherited and the element is not the root of the document tree, use the computed value of the parent element.
> 3. Otherwise use the property's initial value. The initial value of each property is indicated in the property's definition.
>
> — http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specified-value

Comment: Well, that says exactly what I just said- first, the body color is applied, then any parent elements color is applied, and lastly, it is overridden by the specific rule. We're simply arguing semantics.

Comment: I have no idea. I didn't down vote it, but somebody obviously didn't like it.

Comment: Well then. If it's just a matter of semantics I can live with that - at the very least our answers agree with one another.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, somebody down voted my answer as well. ;-)

Comment: Your answer explains why `!important` isn't working, but it does not offer a solution to make it work without making the rule more specific. I do not want to have to create a more specific rule, as I am applying the CSS on Google's homepage (on my own browser), and overfit rules will break often. I just want a rule to override everything forcefully, more specific or not.

Answer (score 4):

You have a more specific rule that is taking precedence on line 94 in main.css:

```
#legend .label {
    color: black;
}
```

Change that to `white` and you are good to go.

Regarding the important, it will take precedence over other references to `body`, but not to #legend label which is a more specific and applicable selector. Here is a decent article on specificity in CSS: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: I thought CSS specificity can't override the !important directive. Is that not true?

Comment: There are many layers of specificity and it's all affected by the way CSS cascades- since you are referencing the #legend .label directly it is not inheriting from the body and thus !important has no bearing.

Comment: This is inaccurate. While `#legend .label` is indeed more specific than `body`, it is irrelevant, because both of them are targeting different elements altogether.

Comment: That is correct, they are; however, @DonnyP is correct in thinking that setting the color on body would make his text white- if there was not a color set on #legend .label. The specific rule renders that text's inheritance of the body color null and void. I hardly consider that irrelevant.

Comment: I agree with @mifi79 and would like to add that what you know is true but it would take effect only one the important is used on the same selector. ex. if it was  #legend .label{color: black} and #legend .label{color: white !important;} then it would be effective. In the present case the property was not directly applied to the selector rather it was inherited from its super parent i.e. the body.

Comment: @mifi79 I think we're having a different understanding of the word "specific" there. Note that specificity has a very - excuse the tired pun - specific meaning in CSS: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity