# font-weight: bold !important is overridden

Tags: css

I run into a situation where I need to override font-weight property. However, even though I use !important to increase its priority, it still gets overridden by other styles. As you can see in the following example, I am expecting hello world to be bolded, but it is using font-weight: normal instead. Any ideas? Thanks

```css
body {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

div {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Comment: `div` is a more specific selector than inheriting from `body`. Specificity of css rules is key; adding `!important` would override another font-weight setting on the body but, again, div is more specific than inheritance.  See [MDN Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider the universal selector if you want to make your font-weight to apply on the div and also other tags. *(as i suspect you want to make all the page bold)*

In your case you are appling the style to **body** and not the `div` element and style of child element always override the parent style even with the use of `!important`. So this rule will only work with element that inherit the font-weight from the body.

```css
body *{
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

div {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Also find a related thread talking about the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074577/css-important-does-not-override-styles-from-external-stylesheets

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with binding priority of the styles. A way to resolve this is to make the rule more specific, e.g. by targeting `body div` instead:

```css
body div {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

div {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
```

**However**, please don't do this unless absolutely completely unavoidable. `!important` is a hack at best. If you are in control of the HTML, just introduce a class or use a more relevant selector.

Comment: Yes. Really. Don't use `!important` - fix your rules instead. `!important` was created for _end users_ to be able to override a site's style.

Comment: @StephenP i guess we all agree with this but maybe we have this situation as if you read the question he said `I run into a situation where I need to overwrite font-weight property` : so he's in a situation where he cannot adjust class or update his CSS ... and he show us a simplified example of his issue which am sure is more complicated

Comment: @TemaniAfif - agreed, mostly, except he _can_ adjust his CSS since that's what the question is about — you can almost always be more specific with your rule rather than resort to _!important_, like using `body div` in this answer.

Comment: @StephenP for one element i agree, but am pretty sure he want to apply his style everywhere and that's why i provided my solution that he accept by the way ... so it confirmes that somehow he wanted to make all his page bold

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I fully agree to what you said here. Please don't think too much into this simplified example though, it's not a real use case...